# div smooth scroll animation complete callback

Tags: jquery, smooth-scrolling, jquery-callback

I am using your plugin DivSmoothScroll for one of my websites.
Works very well.
I have enabled touchScrolling on it.
I need to know if there is a callback function that gets called when the user drags the div and releases it.
I have two smoothScroll divs on one page, I want to control the second div based on the drag/scroll movement done on the first div.

Please advise.

Comment: http://smoothdivscroll.com/callbacks.html

Comment: @PedroEstrada there is no callback function for animation complete in that list. I had already checked it.
My requirement is to be able to call a function when the user is dragging the scroll div and when its released.

Comment: Are you talking about mouseover and mouseout? if so, you can set up those events with jquery after the scroll is initialized. The plugin has `mouseOverRightHotSpot` so maybe that can help you.

Comment: no @PedroEstrada, I need to know if there is a callback function that gets called when the user starts dragging the div or the dragging animation gets complete. None of the callback functions mentioned in http://smoothdivscroll.com/callbacks.html cater to that need.

Answer (score 0):

Very interesting question!

When you asked it, there where no such callbacks implemented in Smooth Div Scroll, but now that you mentioned it, I think they should be implemented. So that's what I have done. :-)

If you check out [the repository on GitHub](https://github.com/tkahn/Smooth-Div-Scroll) , you'll find that two new callbacks are implemented. Use them like this:

```
$("#makeMeScrollable").smoothDivScroll({
    touchStopped: function(eventObj, data) {
        alert("Touch stopped");
    },
    touchMoved: function(eventObj, data) {
        alert("Touch moved");
    },
});
```

These callbacks just forward the callbacks that jQuery.kinetic has. Please note that they are not documented on smoothdivscroll.com (yet).

I hope you find them helpful - good luck with the scrolling!